# Converting JSON hash into URL to be used in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using an API that has a URL in the response (a JSON hash). I'm trying to take the response, parse the URL and use the URL in a link_to helper in my rails view. My current JSON parsing isn't doing the trick.

```
# The Response
{"url":"https://demo.foobar.net/t=54e85a9f-008b-481c-986d-69881208713e"}

# Controller Action to Parse
@url = JSON.parse(response.to_json)

# Rails View
<%= link_to "Sign Document", @url %>

# Rendered HTML
<a href="/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhttps://demo.foobar.net/t=54e85a9f-008b-481c-986d-69881208713e">Click Here!</a>
```

I need to parse the JSON hash to ensure the output of my rails link_to helper is:

```
 <a href="https://demo.foobar.net/t=54e85a9f-008b-481c-986d69881208713e">Click Here!</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are converting your response to json and then parsing it again. U can get the value of url like

```
@url = response["url"]
```